# upgrade to bookworm no keyboard input on old ST5010 tablet

Tags: debian, xorg

I have an old Fujitsu Siemens Stylistic ST5010 tablet and upgraded it from Jessie to Bookworm and installed MATE as GUI. Now, I have a problem with the keyboard which is connected with a (likely proprietary) IR link: it works while GRUB runs and initially in a terminal, but once the GUI is started, no keyboard input. I can start with a keyboard attached via USB..

I found [a hint](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=187360) and found that `wacom` was installed, and added `wacom_w8001` (and for good measure `wacom_serial4`) which did not help.  The wacom pointer works ok, but not the keyboard.

During boot I see a failure:

```
Okt 31 14:20:35 atlanta systemd[1]: console-setup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Okt 31 14:20:35 atlanta console-setup.sh[301]: /usr/bin/setupcon: 999: cannot open /tmp/tmpkbd.V13CcX: No such file
Okt 31 14:20:35 atlanta systemd[1]: console-setup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 31 14:20:35 atlanta systemd[1]: Failed to start console-setup.service - Set console font and keymap.
```

and do not understand, if it relates.

It seems that at a basic level, the connection to the keyboard is there but not visible in the GUI; I do not have the knowledge  and do not see how I should further investigate. I can still run the old Jessie (XFCE) installation to compare, but do not see, where to look.